# Get LUIS Intent and Entities without LUISGEN

Tags: azure-language-understanding

1. Currently I'm using LUISGen to help my bot to get Intent and Entities easily in C#.
2. But we are building a bot automation, and do not want to use LUISGen, because we can't ask user to use LUISGEN to generate the C# class.
3. So, which is the best/latest method for me to call LUIS to get Intent and Entities?

Is it the API method at https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c2f ?

But I can't seems to find any documentation for getting Intent and Entities with User Utterances.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-get-started-get-intent-from-rest?pivots=programming-language-csharp) documentation to get intents using endpoint REST API. Also, depending on what exactly you want to query for, you can make use of the [LUIS API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c1d).

1. LUIS [get entity](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c1d)
2. LUIS [get intent](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9c1a)

Hope this helps.